# Related posts in Next.js markdown blog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a website under development on next.js . a blog is already ready there. I am wondering if it is possible to make a blog of similar articles that are on many sites. The tag that is assigned to the article can serve as a filter. I will show my article component [slug.js]

```
import { getAllPosts, getPostBySlug } from "@/lib/getAllData";
import Seo from "@/components/global/seo";
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize';
import { MDXRemote } from 'next-mdx-remote';

import Link from 'next/link'
import Date from '@/lib/date';
import styles from "@/styles/home/posts.module.css"
import PostFooter from "@/components/extra/postFooter"

import Button from '@/components/button';

const _ = require("lodash")
import {translit} from "@/lib/utils"

const components = {
    Button
}

const blogPostHeaderTopTagClasses = [styles.blogPostHeaderTopTag, "mainBtn"].join(" ")

const getTagLink = (tag) => {
    return (
        <Link className={blogPostHeaderTopTagClasses} href={`/blog/tag/${tag}`} key={tag}>
            {translit(tag)}
        </Link>
    );
};

const posts = getAllPosts();

export async function getStaticPaths() {

    return {
        paths: posts.map((post) => {
            return {
                params: {
                    slug: post.slug,
                },
            };
        }),
        fallback: false,
    };
}


  export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
    const post =  getPostBySlug(slug);
    const mdxSource = await serialize(post.content);

    const postIndex = posts.findIndex((post) => post.slug === slug)
    const prev = posts[postIndex + 1] || null
    const next = posts[postIndex - 1] || null

    return {
      props: {
        post,
        frontmatter: post.data,
        content: mdxSource,
        prev,
        next
      }
    };
  }


  export default function PostPage({ frontmatter, content, prev, next }) {

    const url = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.href : '';

    return (
        <>

            <Seo
                title={`${frontmatter.title}`}
                description={`${frontmatter.description}`}
                canonicalUrl={url}
                ogImageUrl={`http://localhost:3000/api/og?title=${frontmatter.title}&description=${frontmatter.description}&date=${frontmatter.date}`}
                ogType={"article"}
            />

            <article className={styles.blogPost}>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <header className={styles.blogPostHeader}>
                        <div className={styles.blogPostHeaderTop}>
                            {frontmatter.tags.map(tag => getTagLink(tag)).reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, '', curr])}
                        </div>
                        <h1 className={styles.blogPostTitle}>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
                        <p className={styles.postDesc}>{frontmatter.description}</p>
                        <span className={styles.blogPostHeaderDate}>
                            <Date dateString={frontmatter.date} />
                        </span>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <div className="wrapperRead">
                    <MDXRemote {...content}  components = {components} />
                    <PostFooter
                        title={frontmatter.title}
                    />
                    {(next || prev) && (
                    <div className={styles.prevNextPosts}>
                        {prev && (
                            <div className={styles.prevNextPostsItem}>
                                <h6>
                                    Предыдущая статья
                                </h6>
                                <h5>
                                    <Link className={styles.prevNextPostsItemLink} href={`/blog/${prev.slug}`}>{prev.title}</Link>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                        )}
                        {next && (
                            <div className={styles.prevNextPostsItem}>
                                <h6>
                                    Следующая статья
                                </h6>
                                <h5>
                                    <Link className={styles.prevNextPostsItemLink} href={`/blog/${next.slug}`}>{next.title}</Link>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </article>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Let's say embed the related posts block under the `(next|| prev)` block. I need to somehow match one of the tags that the currently open article has and other articles that have one of the same tags. Is the information provided by the code above enough, or is something else needed? Who will tell you what to do?